# Load bulk data into BigQuery partitioned table with different partitions-based data

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to load CSV data into BigQuery partitioned table.My CSV file containing different partitioned data.How can i load entire CSV file to BigQuery partitioned table so that particular csv partitioned data goes to respective partition in BigQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load your entire CSV data into temporary staging table and then use queries of type

```
bq query --destination_table=table$20170115 
  "SELECT * FROM temp WHERE part='2017-01-15'"
```

To copy appropriate data into their partitions.

Comment: In this case we have to change the value of part manually.i just want to load whole csv file in one go.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, BigQuery DOES NOT support partitioning based on field(s) in data!
So, obviously you cannot load whole CSV and expect it to be partitioned.
Hopefully this will be changed soon  - you can track respective [`feature request`](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35905817)

Meantime, some of your options are:

- process your csv file outside of BigQuery to split one file to respective dates (one csv per date) and then load them one-by-one into respective partition of (in advance prepared partitioned) table

or

- load whole csv as is into BigQuery and then process / select one-by-one day into respective partition of (still in advance prepared partitioned) table

Depends on your particular case one or another option can be better for you - you to decide.
From BigQuery cost point of view  - first option seems cheaper to me